# iOS: FacebookSDKCoreKit framework - file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am trying to add the Facebook SDK to my iOS app.  I am following the directions from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

I am at the step where you put:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

My problem is that I am getting an error message that says **'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found**

As you see the framework is clearly in the project:
[image]

I followed the directions correctly when setting up my information in the .plist, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: found the problem, it was this part: Also, in your Build Settings, look at this field: "Framework Search Paths" You should have something like this: /Users/[username]/Documents/FacebookSDK

Comment: good catch over there

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Sorry, but if I have FacebookSDK in my project folder?

Comment: @anivaler I would think a similar scenario, check your Build Phases>Compile Sources to make sure that the files are all included there